# Two ODEs, why is one solution the solution of the other?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

This question is based on Zeidler II/B, Problem 30.2.

Consider the ODE: find $u:[0,T] \to \mathbb{R}^n$ s.t. 
$$u'(t) = F(t,u(t))$$
$$u(0) = u_0$$
given $F:[0,T]\times \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ Caratheodory. We know that if it has a solution, it satisfies $|u(t)| \leq C$ for all $t$. Let us suppose that there is $f \in L^1(0,T)$ such that $|F(t,a)| \leq f(t)$ for all $t$ and all $a$ such that $|a| \leq 2C$.

Consider the ODE
$$v'(t) = \hat F(t,v(t))$$ 
$$v(0) = u_0$$
where (*)
$$\hat F(t,a) = 
\begin{cases}
F(t,a) &: |a| \leq 2C\\
F(t, \frac{2Ca}{|a|}) &: |a| \geq 2C
\end{cases}.$$
This ODE has a solution, since $\hat F(t,a)$ is dominated by $f$ on the whole of $\mathbb{R}^n$ by definition of $\hat F$.

**How do I show that the solution $v$ of the second ODE is also a solution of the first ODE (Zeidler claims this)?** Of course it's obvious if the solution $|v(t)| \leq 2C$, but how about if it's greater than $2C$?

(*) - in Zeidler, the second case is given as $F(t,2a/C|a|)$, which I think is wrong since it would not make $\hat F(t,\cdot)$ continuous.

---

I posted this on MO https://mathoverflow.net/questions/213007/two-odes-why-is-one-the-solution-of-the-other-caratheodory-ode

Comment: Just to check: are you sure it's not $F(t,2C\frac{a}{|a|})$ in the def. of $\hat{F}$? This just seems more natural as $\hat{F}$ is then continuous in the second variable.

Comment: @Winther Just checked, it is as in the OP.

Comment: I think you're right. It is probably a typo in the book which I got this from (Zeidler).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, note that if $0<b<T$ and $u:[0,b] \to \mathbb{R}^n$ satisfies
$$u'(t) = F(t,u(t))$$
$$u(0) = u_0$$
then we also have that it satisfies $|u(t)| \leq C$ for all $t\in [0,b]$.

Now, we know that $|v(0)|=|u_0|=|u(0)| \leq C$. Suppose there is $t_1\in [0,T]$ such that $|v(t_1)| > 2C$. Then there is $t_2\in [0,t_1)$ such that, $|v(t_2)| = 2C$ and, for all $t\in [0,t_2]$, $|v(t)| \leq 2C$.

Then $v$ restricted to $[0,t_2]$ satisfies 
$$v'(t) = F(t,v(t))$$
$$v(0) = u_0$$

So, by our initial remark, we have that $|v(t)| \leq C$ for all $t\in [0,t_2]$. But $|v(t_2)| = 2C>C$. Contradiction. So there is no such $t_1\in [0,T]$ such that $|v(t_1)| > 2C$.

Comment: Thanks!! Btw have you seen this result in some other book than in Zeidler? I cannot find it anywhere.

Comment: @C_Al  This result, exactly as stated and prove here, I have not seen in any book. HOWEVER, this is a rather standard technique in Dynamical Systems. It consists in "changing the ODE"  away from where a solution is (or would be) to make the ODE a "better behaved one" without affecting the solution.  In this situation, the proof that the change in the ODE does not  affect the solution is generally done using the same technique I used in the answer.